# How can I invoke system call of Linux/UNIX in golang

Tags: go, system-calls

For some reasons, I need invoke some system calls of the system(Linux) 
I checked the documentation of the 'syscall' package and couldn't find anything about it.

Then I just saw a project (https://github.com/AllenDang/w32/blob/master/kernel32.go) which wraps  windows apis. I read the source code of it a bit.

It uses

```
modkernel32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
```

to load the dynamic library. However, there is no documentation for function NewLazyDLL()

I am sure there should be a similar function for Linux/UNIX. Is there any one can tell 
me the name of the function or the way to invoke system call of Linux in Golang or 
load functions from libc.so ?

**More details**

I want to invoke system call 'daemon' or 'fork'(I want to daemonize the process)  because I cannot find golang library provides them.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  The `syscall` package is the right package for the direct system call interface, but it is hard to give any advice without knowing what you want to do.  You won't find DLL loading in the UNIX version of the package though, since that is not part of the system call interface.

Comment: Thanks James for your reply.Actually I just want to know how I can get the system call interface.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `daemon` style function in the Go standard library at the moment.  There is [an open bug about adding such a feature](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=227), but it has been deferred until after the Go 1.1 release.  I would suggest reading the bug report for some of the reasons it isn't quite as simple as it might first appear.

There are other ways to run daemon processes apart from having the daemon fork itself though.  Modern init daemons like Upstart and Systemd can manage such daemon processes for you, for instance.

Comment: Thanks James. I won't use fork/daemon in my program but I am still wondering that how I can invoke system call of unix. I found there are two functions called Syscall/Syscall6 but there is no any docs for it. Are these two functions can be used to invoke system call of unix?

Comment: The functions in the `systemcall` package give you access to most system calls (as you correctly surmised in your question).  For example, `syscall.Read` will invoke the `SYS_read` system call.  If the particular system call you're after isn't covered by the package, please ask about them specifically.  The answer above covers your specific question about daemonising a process.

Comment: The syscall package exposes (almost) all syscalls of the platform you're on. The contents of this package are different among different platforms. Use source files with platform suffixes, such as foo_linux.go and foo_windows.go. go build will only compile files with matching suffixes. This is a nice and clean way to factor out platform dependant code.